# How to read ssh keys from vault and write to file with salt

Tags: salt-stack, hashicorp-vault

I hope someone can help me .

I have stored ssh keys in vault as a secret. With saltstack config I am reading the secret with a pillar. Like this

```
  docker:
  {% set sshkey = salt['vault'].read_secret('super/secret/sshinfo', 'slackbot') %}
  sshkey: | 
    {{ sshkey | indent(4) }}
```

And `init.sls` file looks like this:

```
{% set docker_config = pillar['docker'] %}
    git-key:
      file.managed:
        - name: /root/.ssh/slack-bot
        - contents: {{ docker_config.sshkey }}
        - mode: 400
        - user: root
```

Which works great and I get the ssh key by typing `salt-call pillar.items`

However, when I run `salt-call state.apply` I get the following error message

```
local:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:docker' failed: could not find expected ':'
```

Which is driving me nuts!

I read [Mulitline string on Github](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/5480) that in order to write mulitline with salt you need to have `| indent(4)` (as an example).

Does someone have any ideas? Would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a while I tried to change `indent(4)` to `indent(5)`, but it didn't gave up the error. So I also tried to change `content` to be

```
  - contents: |
    {{ docker_config.sshkey | indent(5) }}
```

Which fixed the problem and is now working.

Hope anyone who has similar problems find this useful.

Cheers!